# Solution to the system $a_1\sin\theta+b_1\cos\theta=x+c_1$, $a_2\sin\theta+b_2\cos\theta=x+c_2$ does not satisfy initial equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have the following system of equations:

\begin{align*}
a_1\sin(\theta) + b_1\cos(\theta) &= x + c_1 \\
a_2\sin(\theta) + b_2\cos(\theta) &= x + c_2 \\
\end{align*}

And I am trying to solve for $\theta$ and $x$. I substitute $x$, get
$$(a_2-a_1)\sin(\theta)+(b_2-b_1)\cos(\theta) = c_2-c_1$$

Calling $a = a_2-a_1$, $b = b_2-b_1$, $c = c_2-c_1$ I solve this equation by usual methods and arrive at the answers
$$\sin(\theta+\phi) = \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
with $\cos(\phi) =\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$

However, substituting the result in either first or second equation yields different values for $x$. What is the problem here? Is there no unique solution?

Comment: Please show the values of $x$ you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. Maybe some miscalculations?

I did some "rough" verification of your suggested method (by rough I mean taking inverse trig without seriously thinking about domains) and it seems fine.

$$\sin(\theta+\phi) = \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\implies \theta= \sin^{-1}(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})-\phi$$
$$\therefore \theta= \sin^{-1}(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})-\cos^{-1}(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})$$

substitution to the first equation :
$$\begin{align}
x&=a_1sin\theta+b_1\cos\theta-c_1\\
&=a_1(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2}}\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}})\\
&+b_1(\sqrt{1-\frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2}}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}}\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})\\
&-c_1\\
\end{align}$$

and similarly if we do with the equation 2 we get the same expression except $a_1, b_1, c_1$ are replaced by $a_2, b_2, c_2$ so to prove that the  two solutions are the same we subtract them and show that it yields $0$. Note that when subtracting we get :

$$\begin{align}
asin\theta+b\cos\theta-c
&=a(\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2}}\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}})\\
&+b(\sqrt{1-\frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2}}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2}}\frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}})\\
&-c\\
\end{align}$$

The right hand side might look ugly but it does simplify to zero!

Comment: I see, well, the math does not lie, what probably lies is my code, I will have to recheck it forth time now. Thank you very much for the verification!